# Redirecting to another PHP page, then going back with filled fields

Tags: php, html, redirect, field

I have been needing a way to, once I redirect to a PHP page to review data, have the ability go back to the original page with the fields filled as they were before redirecting.  I can think of several messy ways of doing this but nothing I am willing to do.  Is there a standard way of doing this?

Comment: I would store it in session over a cookie (granted the session hash is stored in a cookie). But this is sort of what session was made for. This will store the data in a file on the server and save it from being on the user's computer / having to be transfered each time over the wire to be read / accessed. (Ie the page reloads)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the sensitivity of the data, you could store it in a session variable and check for the presence of POST or GET variables prior to falling back to the session variables when the form is being displayed.

You could obviously wrap the above up nicely, but I don't suspect there's an easier way around it if you're trying to keep the query string clean.